# Calling Linux functions from R

Tags: linux, r

I have been using the `system` function within `R` as part of my workflow to call Linux commands. One item that is puzzling to me is that certain functions seem to work and others do not.

For example, if I call `system("ps")` within `R`, it gives me a list of process ids, Time, and the Cmd.

But if I invoke `system("top")`, I get the following error:

`TERM environment variable not set.`

Anyone know how to fix this? My workflow consists of running `RStudio` server from a browser that sits on a Windows box. It is conveinient for me to not have to open up `PuTTy` in order to keep tabs on `R` processes.

Comment: You may want to rethink more carefully which programs you can, or cannot, call via `system()`.  Hint: interactive programs won't work well.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. For long processes, I like to run `system("nohup lassso.R &")` in `RStudio` and then move on with my work. It is nice to check the memory usage and number of processes being forked with `RStudio`. Is there another way?

Comment: Actually, depending on the terminal setting it even works ... but it still makes little sense.  There is no magic to `system()` -- it  more or less just executes a shell with the command you give and then waits ...

Comment: Why would you do that?  Why would you not launch a job _in the shell where the shell has proper job control_ ?

Comment: This is helpful. It seems probable what I am trying to do is foolish. I just thought it would be convenient to do everything though `RStudio` if possible

Comment: You can easily access the shell in RStudio via the `Tools` menu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run top in 'batch' mode you can use it in a system call.

```
system("top -n 1 -b")
```

The -n 1 option runs a single iteration

the -b option runs in batch mode instead of interactive

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message, the TERM environmental variable is not set.  Try to set it with `Sys.setenv`

```
Sys.setenv(TERM = "xterm")
```

Comment: Nope.  `top` wants run and refresh in til `q` is pressed. It makes no sense to be called in `system`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, thank you.  I am aware the top runs until you press `q`.  If you just want to quickly view and exit out it could be useful if you suspect other processes are using up resources.  Clearly not something to be part of a workflow.

Comment: We are sort-of both saying the same.  `top` is an interactive program, and it reports so side-effects so good in a workflow as you say.

Comment: I get the following error message with this  `top: failed tty get`. I do not have root privileges on this machine, if that matters.

Comment: I just tried in a pure shell session, multiplexed within `tmux`, and  it works just fine. I think you are once again assuming that RStudio is something that it isn't, in this a case a proper terminal.

Comment: To be fair to me, working in a terminal emulator like Putty is much less pleasant compared to an actual terminal.

Comment: You are not forced to use `putty`.

Comment: My workplace doesn't really have an alternative besides putty. It is not the ideal setup. It would be nice if I never had to use Windows at all.